# Passing arguments via POST with PHP/PECL OAuth extension

Tags: php, oauth, pecl

I'm fairly new to the concept of OAuth and I'm trying to interact with the new Rdio API. I've managed to figure out the authentication using the PECL OAuth functions, but Rdio requires arguments to be passed in via POST and I can't figure out how that is done. The authentication works: the user is bounced to Rdio's site and asked to approve the application, and they are then returned to the site. After that, though, the request making calls to the API fails.

Here's some info on the Rdio API: http://developer.rdio.com/docs/REST/

Here's the code I have for authentication... the lines in italics are what I believe should make the call to the API requesting the method named "currentUser"

```
$req_url = 'http://api.rdio.com/oauth/request_token';
$authurl = 'https://www.rdio.com/oauth/authorize';
$acc_url = 'http://api.rdio.com/oauth/access_token';
$callback = 'http://localhost/test.php';
$api_url = 'http://api.rdio.com/1';
$conskey = 'vmu7x6u4rk8vae8dn28h';
$conssec = 'GrY7gF';

session_start();

if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['state']==1) $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
try {
  $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
  $oauth->enableDebug();
  if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
    $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_url);
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    header('Location: '.$authurl.'?oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token'].'&oauth_callback='.urlencode($callback));
    exit;
  } else if($_SESSION['state']==1) {
    $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
    $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($acc_url);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
  } 

  $args = "method=currentUser";

  $oauth->setToken($_SESSION['token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
  $oauth->fetch("$api_url", $args);
  $json = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());
  print_r($json);

} catch(OAuthException $E) {
  print_r($E);
}
```

The message I get back:

`Warning: OAuth::fetch(http://api.rdio.com/1?oauth_consumer_key=vmu7x6u4rktv468vae8dn28h&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_nonce=12606272174d85622ad26ce8.80381248&oauth_timestamp=1300587050&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_token=238zec5p4rpcpbfd8j36sjggz3jfsssybhxgcn9kvmmrmdxr3t4f2cnspt4dg5xf&oauth_signature=1mZhJ9AUbi0sm6qhNaAntumAckU%3D) [function.OAuth-fetch]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 596`

The problem is most likely that the arguments (method=currentUser) aren't being passed via POST properly. Does anyone have any idea how to do this using PECL's OAuth extensions?

Comment: $callback = 'http://localhost/test.php'; ? shouldn't that be $callback = 'http://conectablehost.com/test.php';

Comment: Yes, I just changed the host to get the specifics out of my code. The same way I used fake key and secret keys at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this looking for the answer, here is what I found works:

To perform a POST OAuth signed request, you need to set the OAuth object to send using POST instead of GET by adding this method before the `fetch()` method:

```
$oauth->setAuthType(OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM);
```

Even if you're using the `OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST` parameter in the `fetch()` method, the OAuth instance itself needs to have `setAuthType(OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM)` called on it first.

The code for the specific example I was citing is:

```
    if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['state']==1) $_SESSION['state'] = 0;

$oauth = new OAuth($rdio_conskey,$rdio_conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
$oauth->enableDebug();
if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
  $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($rdio_req_url);
  $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
  $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
  header('Location: '.$rdio_auth_url.'?oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token'].'&oauth_callback='.$callbackurl);
  exit;
} else if($_SESSION['state']==1) {
  $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
  $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($rdio_acc_url);
  $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
  $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
  $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
}   

$oauth = new OAuth($rdio_conskey, $rdio_conssec, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
$oauth->setToken($access_token_info['oauth_token'],$access_token_info['oauth_token_secret']);
$oauth->setAuthType(OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM);

$oauth->fetch($rdio_api_url, array("method" => "currentUser", "extras" => "username"), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_FORM);
$json = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());    

print_r($json);
```

Comment: You can also set the auth type to `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION` (the default) to encode the parameters into the HTTP `Authorization` header. Much cleaner request to debug, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Using `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM` is only a workaround.

Pecl's oauth extension version 1.2.3 has [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67650); `getRequestToken` and `getAccessToken` use GET requests instead of POST as the RFC wants.

You can work around this bug by passing `OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST` as 3rd parameter to `getRequestToken` and 4th parameter to `getAccessToken`. Yes, those parameters [are undocumented](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67649).

---

Version 1.2.4 of pecl/oauth will default to POST.

Comment: Hello, how can i install OAuth in GoDaddy VPS server? i searched lot but there is no solution, can you pls help me?